# WCF Configuration AddressFilter mismatch

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-binding, wcf-configuration

I am having WCF configuration woes. I have a WCF Webservice that I want to be able to access through a web browser using GET parameters (and eventually in PHP with simplexml_load_file()). My Visual Studio Solution is set up as a WCF Service Library project containing an Interface (where the service is defined), a class (where the service is implemented, and an app.config (which was there by default). I also have a WCF Service Project which contains a .svc file (which points to my class) and a web.config. My Service Interface is designed like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using RTXEngineLib.externalLibrary;
namespace RTXEngineLib {
    [ServiceContract(Name = "RTXEngine", Namespace = "")]
    public interface IRTXEngine {
        [OperationContract(Name = "GetCountryList"), WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetCountryList/", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        List<Country> GetCountryList();
        [OperationContract(Name = "GetRegions"), WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetRegions/?countryID={countryID}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        List<Region> GetRegions(int countryID);
        [OperationContract(Name = "GetExchangeAvailability"), WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetExchangeAvailability/?countryID={countryID}&month={month}&year={year}&regionID={regionID}&resortID={resortID}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        AvailabilityList GetExchangeAvailability(int countryID, String month, int year, String regionID = "?", String resortID = "");
        [OperationContract(Name = "GetResortsForDate"), WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetResortsForDate/?month={month}&year={year}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        List<AvailabilityList> GetResortsForDate(String month, int year);
        [OperationContract(Name = "GetRegionLists"), WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetRegionLists/", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        List<RegionList> GetRegionLists();
        [OperationContract(Name = "GetRegionListCacheState"), WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetRegionListCacheState/", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        Boolean GetRegionListCacheState();
    }
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class LoginRequestResponse {
        [DataMember]
        public Boolean Success { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public AccountStanding AccountStanding { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public double FTXBalance { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<ContractData> Contracts { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public enum AccountType {
        [DataMember]
        NonAuthenticatedAccount,
        [DataMember]
        AC,
        [DataMember]
        PT,
        [DataMember]
        Wks
    }
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public enum AccountStanding {
        [DataMember]
        NotAuthenticated,
        [DataMember]
        Good,
        [DataMember]
        Mixed,
        [DataMember]
        Delinquent
    }
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public struct RegionList {
        [DataMember]
        public String CountryName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String CountryID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public struct Country {
        [DataMember]
        public String CountryName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String ID { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public struct Region {
        [DataMember]
        public String RegionName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String ID { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public struct User {
        [DataMember]
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String Address { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String City { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String State { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String Zip { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String CountryOfResidence { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public struct ContractData {
        [DataMember]
        public String ContractID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public AccountType AccountType { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public AccountStanding AccountStanding { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String AvailablePoints { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String UnavailablePoints { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String Usage { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public struct PointsData {
        [DataMember]
        public String ContractID { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class GlobalAppCache {
        [DataMember]
        public static DateTime RegionListsLastUpdate { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public static List<RegionList> CachedRegionLists { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my App.config for the library looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5555555555555555">
      <section name="RTXEngineLib.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RTXEngineLib.RTXEngineLib">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="RTXEngineLib.IRTXEngineLib">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/RTXEngineLib/RTXEngineLib/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <applicationSettings>
    <RTXEngineLib.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="RTXEngineLib_externalLibrary" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://externalLibrary.com/websvcs/externalLibrary.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </RTXEngineLib.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

And then my Web.config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Web" sendTimeout="00:03:00" maxBufferSize="131072"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="131072" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Basic" name="RTXEngineLib.RTXEngineLib">
        <endpoint address="http://devrtxengine.telemark/RTXService.svc"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Web" name="Basic"
          contract="RTXEngineLib.IRTXEngine" listenUri="http://devrtxengine.myserver/RTXService.svc" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="Basic">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="Web">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetBinding="webHttpBinding"
            httpGetBindingConfiguration="" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

When I attempt to run my service using `http://devrtxengine.myserver/RTXService.svc/GetCountryList` I end up with the following error:

```
<Fault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none">
<Code>
<Value>Sender</Value>
<Subcode>
<Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:DestinationUnreachable</Value>
</Subcode>
</Code>
<Reason>
<Text xml:lang="en-US">
The message with To 'http://devrtxengine.telemark/RTXService.svc/GetCountryList' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.
</Text>
</Reason>
</Fault>
```

I suspect that there is some kind of mismatch between my App.config and my Web.config, but every time I try to change something in my Web.config I break my service even more than it is already broken. Does anyone with more WCF experience have any advice?

Comment: The app.config for the service library is irrelevant - it won't be used.   The Web.config for the WCF Service is the config file that will be used by your library.  How are you calling the service?  Do you have a separate client, are you using a test tool, etc?

Comment: I am calling it by typing the URL into my web browser (which is how I need to service able to work when complete), as shown in the tiny paragraph just before the error message. `http://devrtxengine.myserver/RTXService.svc/GetCountryList`

Comment: I noticed that the endpoint adress was devrtxengine.telemark, but you have the listenUri as devrtxengine.myserver.  Not sure if that's a typo or if it would make a difference.  Also, you can try adding the WebHttpBinding to the behaviors - see [Resolving Configuration Error in WCF AddressFilter Mismatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339421/resolving-configuration-error-in-wcf-addressfilter-mismatch) for an example.

Comment: @Tim , the link you posted pointed me in the right direction. I needed to add a Service Behaviour and an Endpoint Bahaviour (both) for webHttp, I had previously only configured the Service Behaviour. If you wouldn't mind posting an answer with the link you included, I would be more than happy to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: posted.  Glad it helped you out.

Comment: Refer this article to know about configuration mismatch(if any) in your application. http://www.robbagby.com/rest/rest-in-wcf-part-iv-hi-rest-exposing-a-service-via-get-configuring-the-service/

Comment: For information, I just ran across the same issue but with SoapUI (for consuming) and this article quickly gave the answer : http://javiercrespoalvez.com/2010/09/using-soapui-to-consume-ws-addressing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that the endpoint adress was devrtxengine.telemark, but you have the listenUri as devrtxengine.myserver. Not sure if that's a typo or if it would make a difference. Also, you can try adding the WebHttpBinding to the behaviors - see [Resolving Configuration Error in WCF AddressFilter Mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339421/resolving-configuration-error-in-wcf-addressfilter-mismatch) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I check when I run into that error:

```
* endpoint is missing in web.config, 
* doublecheck the UriTemplate path
* make sure to set an endpointBehavior inside behaviors, such as 
  < endpointBehaviors >
    < behavior name =" web" >
      < webHttp />
    </ behavior >
  </ endpointBehaviors >
* and set behaviorConfiguration="web" on endpoint your individual endpoint
```

Comment: Happy to help! :-)

Comment: Thank you, dan! I had to trudge through many stack overflows and Google search results but after fussing w/many nodes/attributes of my web.config for a while your edit suggestions were the ones that got my WCF working. Thanks!