# WCF configuration help - can't get it right

Tags: wcf, web-config, behavior, endpoint

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now. I'm trying to host a WCF service in IIS, so our other websites can access the data that this service will expose. Writing the code was fairly straightforward, it's the configuration that I can't get right, no matter what I try.

What I'm trying to achieve:

1. Have the service behind http and https at http(s)://service.motors.coop (We don't have the SSL cert yet)
2. Be able to be called by .net, PHP, iOS, Android etc (although I'm sure this isn't config based)
3. Test the methods by accessing them via the browser eg http://service.motors.coop/motorsservice.svc/ShowClientIp

Whenever I try and access http://service.motors.coop/motorsservice.svc/ShowClientIp I get the following error:

> The message with To 'http://service.motors.coop/MotorsService.svc/ShowClientIp' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.

There are so many config options I don't know where to start, although I've read countless articles and even bought a book - it's far too complicated!

Would any kind soul help me out with my config file?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- removed -->
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="MotorsWcfService.MotorsService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="MotorsServiceEndpoint" contract="MotorsWcfService.IMotorsService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="https://service.motors.coop/MotorsService"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndpointBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false"/>
```

**Update:** After going through the wizard to create my config I now have this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <standardEndpoints>
        <webHttpEndpoint>
            <standardEndpoint name="WebHttpEndPoint" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
        </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WebHttpBinding" />
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="MotorsWcfService.MotorsService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
            <endpoint address="http://service.motors.coop" binding="webHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding" contract="MotorsWcfService.IMotorsService" />
            <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

However, I still get this error:

> The message with To 'http://service.motors.coop/MotorsService.svc/ShowClientIp' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.

Comment: Try loading the configuration with the UI - much easier to detect problems. Open the VS command prompt, and write svcconfigeditor.exe. Check this link out : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009.aspx. You can then load the configuration, and it will validate the config for a start.

Comment: @StephenBorg Thanks for the response. I've gone through the wizard as best I can but I still have the 'The message with To 'http://service.motors.coop/MotorsService.svc/ShowClientIp' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.' error.

I've updated my post with my new config. Do you have any idea what can be causing this error now?

Answer (score -1):

Please check this links [AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher - the msg with To](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293721/addressfilter-mismatch-at-the-endpointdispatcher-the-msg-with-to) and [Resolving Configuration Error in WCF AddressFilter Mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339421/resolving-configuration-error-in-wcf-addressfilter-mismatch) and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b5ae495b-f5fb-4eed-ae21-2b2280d4fec3/address-filter-mismatch-wcf-addressing

I think this might helps you